# Regex get all text from # to quotation

Tags: javascript, regex

Okay so I currently have:

`/(#([\"]))/g;`

I want to be able to check for a string like:

`#23ad23"`

Whats wrong with my regex?

Comment: Is this the entirety of your problem? If so, regex probably isn't necessary. I do know, though, that it might be better in certain cases, if your problem extends further.

Comment: When you ask for regular expression cases it is usually good practice to include some test cases, what are you expecting and what you are getting.

Comment: Apologies for badly phrasing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex (`/(#([\"]))/g`) breaks down like this:

without start/end delimiters/flags and capturing braces..

```
#[\"]
```

which just means `#`, followed by `"`, but the square brackets for the class are unnecessary, as there is only one item, so equivalent to...

```
#"
```

I think you want to match all characters between `#` and `"` inclusive (and captured exclusively).

Start with regex like this:

```
#.+?"
```

Which means `#` followed by anything (`.`) one or more times (`+`) un-greedily (`?`) followed by `"`

so with the capturing brackets, and delimeters...

```
/(#(.+?)")/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this how you mean?

```
/(#([^\"]+))/g;
```

This will include everything until it reaches the `"` char.

Answer (score 1):

For minimum match count (bigger-length matches): `#(.+)\"`

For maximum match count (smaller-length matches): `#(.+?)\"`